# What are the advantages of working with the Renesas M16C microcontroller?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, renesas

I know it's the industry standard but what would it add to my simple project? Would it be ok to work with an Arduino for instance?

What are the superior features? I went to their [official website](http://www.renesas.com/products/mpumcu/m16c/) and I did some quick research but I didn't understand much. I had an idea that they have interrupts/timers and many pins but could someone explain more or at least show me  better sources than their official website because it's too formal.

Comment: There's an industry standard microcontroller!!?? Wow ... and its a Renesas M16C ... Who would've thought all that work I did on them *10 years ago* would finally pay off ...

Comment: sorry i don't understand much in this topic so please give me some help if you can

Comment: There isn't really such a thing as "the industry standard microcontroller" except possibly in some manufacturers' marketing departments as something they like to tell themselves.

Comment: @brhans: I'm thinking maybe this is a type of spam.  In any case I voted to close as too opinion based.  Also downvoted due to very badly written.

Comment: its not but you guys have changed the direction of the topic .. i wanted to know about m16c not to argue which micro controller is better

Comment: Your question is too vague, and opinion based for it to be a good fit to this site. Please read the [help] to learn how to ask good questions. The Renesas M16C is not an 'industry standard' for me.  You have given *no explanation* for what you need it for, so we can't offer any rational, evidence-based analysis. So we can't help you. If you can't understand it from the website and its datasheet, then it's unlikely that you are going to be successful using it. Start with something that you can understand using your existing level of knowledge and skill. Then ask specific questions here.

Answer (score 5):

First off, that's not the industry standard. At least, not for any industry I'm familiar with. ARM-based MCUs like the Freescale Kinetis series or ST Micro STM32 series are popular, and PIC 8bit MCUs are popular for less powerful applications. There are many more MCU lines that are used quite a lot.

For DIY projects, however, "industry standard" doesn't matter. What matters is "community standard" i.e. how much support for a given toolchain/platform there is from the community. The DIY community has (for better or for worse) settled on the Arduino, built around an Atmel AVR ATmega328, as a *very* popular MCU platform. There is an open-source, easy to use toolchain (avr-gcc, avrdude, and friends), and you can buy a programmer for $15 or less.

However, the ATmega328 is only an 8bit MCU, and lacks the horsepower required for complicated projects. There are a slew of easy-to-use MCU development boards out there to remedy this.

So, to answer your question, I really can't think of a reason why you should use a Renesas M16C. Use something popular in the community.

Comment: Indeed the availability of a good toolchain is the important thing and lots of support in online communities. Not to forget good readable datasheets. I personally like to add toolchain support on Linux as that is a very comfortable platform for developing your own software and tools in my opinion. Again from a availabiltity of tools, source codes and documentation point of view.

Comment: sorry guys but you've changed the topic of this question , i wanted to know more about the M16C please

Comment: @carlos, read the data sheet for it... Nothing is really superior in general, it's more so what fits your project. If you see a nice feature on the data sheet, then it's worth it to consider... otherwise, why buy something for a feature you're not going to use?
Meaning, we can't say what is better for you, that depends on your project. Usually, you go with a component that meets the need and nothing more.